# How to choose the support vectors after minimizing the objective function?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I'm training a SVM that uses the following objective function:

$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_i{\sum_j{\alpha_i\alpha_j t_i t_j \mathcal{K}(\vec{x_i}, \vec{x_j})}} - \sum_i{\alpha_i}
$$

The objective function is minimized by `scipy.optimize.minimize` in Python. The resulting $\alpha$s can be split between the "huge" ones (several millions) and the others (from $1$ to $10^{-5}$).

Can I consider that only the datapoints corresponding to "huge" alphas will be support vectors? In my previous SVMs, I used a threshold of $10^{-5}$ or $10^{-4}$ to distinguish them, but it doesn't seem to make sense to have such a difference in support vectors weights.